# Is it possible to program a track picker in Spotify?

Tags: javascript, spotify

Is it possible to search for tracks matching a given search string, show them in a spotify list?

Furthermore I want to use a onclick handler and not just play the clicked track. Is that possible and if it is, how?

Comment: Why close this question and downvote? I couldn't find the needed information in the spare documentation. If it's that obvious, please drop a link and add why you would down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Check the preview documentation for how to do search (see the Search object):

http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/